# Retrieve String Join separated by a comma

Tags: vb.net

> Output Expected: I want to return the combinations of 2, in the case below, each separated by a comma and `vbcrlf`, for example:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

and so on...

the problem is that this code below does not.

It returns my values in the line (`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` .. and so on.

how do I make the code from button1 work properly?

```
Function GetCombinations(ByVal depth As Integer, ByVal values As String()) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    If depth > values.Count + 1 Then Return New List(Of String)
    Dim result = New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 To depth - 1
        For y = 0 To values.Count - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                result.Add(values(y))
            Else
                result.Add(values(i - 1) + values(y))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim data_array As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
    "15"}
    Dim result = GetCombinations(2, data_array)
    Dim resultx As String = String.Join(",", result)
    TxtListScanTxt.AppendText(resultx)
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the first loop (`For i = 0 To depth - 1`). You need a single loop. Since you don't need an `IEnumerable(Of String)` as result, apparently, but a single string, append each `data_array[i]` value to a StringBuilder, plus `Environment.Newline` when `(i + 1) Mod depth = 0`, otherwise `","`. The `GetCombinations` method can return the composed string: `return [StringBuilder].ToString().TrimEnd(","c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it - tested and working

```
Public Sub Main()


    Dim data_array As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
"15"}
    dim second as boolean
    dim sb = new stringbuilder()
    For i as integer = 0 To data_array.Length - 1
       if second then
           sb.AppendLine(data_array(i -1) & "," & data_array(i))
           second = false
           continue for
       end if
       if i = data_array.Length - 1 then
          sb.AppendLine(data_array(i))
       end if
       second = true
    next


Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
       Dim data_array As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
   "15"}
        Dim depth As Integer = 3, i As Integer = 1
        Dim result As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For y = 0 To data_array.Count - 1
            If i < depth Then
                result.Append(data_array(y) + ",")
                i += 1
            Else
                result.Append(data_array(y) + vbNewLine)
                i = 1
            End If
        Next

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(result.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim arr = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"}
    '// First, we join all array values with comma to get a string.
    '// Second, we find each group of two digits separated by comma (\d+,\d+)
    '// and replace it ($1) with the same group PLUS the new-line character.
    Dim x = Regex.Replace(String.Join(",", arr), "(\d+,\d+),?", $"$1{vbCrLf}")
End Sub
```

Comment: haha, good one! This is not what student needs to learn though. Students learning loops

Comment: @T.S. IDK whether OP is a student but the code solves the problem! 

Comment: @T.S. Updated code. Technically, nothing has changed. 

Comment: Could you provide a little more explanation to your answer

Comment: @C_Ogoo Added explanation. 